# how to quickly determine the winner of a simple shedding-card game?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, poker, game-theory

### A Naive Shedding Card Game

Given a simple version of a shedding type card game (which is actually a naive version of Dou Di Zhu(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dou_dizhu), the most popular game in china), how can we determine the winner (each player can have up to 20 cards) (is there exists a linear algorithm to solve the problem)?

The object of the game is to get rid of all cards on hand before the opponent. The players are called A and B. The card ranks are:

3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 < T < J < Q < k < A < 2 < r < R  (where T is 10, r, R is small and big joker)

**Definition1**:  Player who can discard any card compile with the **Give-Out-Rule** is called **FirstDiscard player**, while player who can only discard a card that has a higher rank then previous discarded card is called **BeatDiscard player**.

A is the first player to discard a card, so A is always a FirstDiscard player at the beginning. If one choose not to discard a card (because he chooses not to discard or he can not find a valid card to discard), then another become **FirstDiscard player**.

***Give out Rule1:*** Each player can discard a single card at most, Even if you have multiple cards that is the same rank, you can only discard only one of them.

Example1: B winner  4,4,5 < B: 3,4,4,8,T

[image: A: 4,4,5 < B: 3,4,4,8,T]

Explain: B is always the winner, because for any strategy A can possible choose to
play, B can always find a strategy to discard card that leads to winning of B.

Example2: A winner 4,4,5,R > B: 3,4,4,8,T
[image: A: 4,4,5,R > B: 3,4,4,8,T]

Explain: A is always the winner, because there exists a strategy A can choose to use that leads to winning of A regardless of strategies B choose to react.

> The red and blue indicate the state(the cards left in hand) of A and
> B.
>
> The polygon and box shape indicate the player is at **FirstDiscard
> player** state and **BeatDiscard player** state.

[image]
A Relative Graph of tow card sets(A: 4,4,5,R > B: 3,4,4,8,T)

> 1. The Bp value of each card indicates how may opponent's card that this card can be used to beat.
> 2. Cards with the same Bp value form a block.

### The research progress

For now, I can only use the game search tree methods to determine the winner, but the methods takes too long time to process. ***Give out Rule1*** is Actually the first step of my research, the following research give out rule is:

**Definition2**: **solo-card** is defined as card with a specific rank whose count is one. while **pair-card**, **trio-card**, **four-card** are defined as card with a specific rank whose count is two, three, four.

**Definition3**: **solo-card**, **pair-card**, **trio-card**, **four-card** are also called **independent-card**

***Give out Rule2:*** Each player can only discard a kind of **independent-card** each time, if player is at **BeatDiscard player** state, he can only discard the same kind of **independent-card** of previous discarded cards with a higher rank.
SplitCard is not allowed. (if you have a trio-card 555, you can not split the card to be a solo-card 5 and a pair-card 55)

***Give out Rule3:*** The same as **Give out Rule2** except SplitCard is allowed.

**Definition4**: **trio-card** with a **solo-card** is called **trio-solo-kicker-card**, the rank is the same of **trio-card**.

**Definition5**: **trio-card** with a **pair-card** is called **trio-pair-kicker-card**, the rank is the same of **trio-card**.

**Definition6**: **four-card** with two **solo-card** is called **four-2-solo-kicker-card**, the rank is the same of **four-card**.

**Definition7**: **four-card** with two **pair-card** is called **four-2-pair-kicker-card**, the rank is the same of **four-card**.

***Give out Rule4:*** The same as **Give out Rule3** and four additional card types (from Def4 ~ Def7) are allowed to discard.

**Definition8**: **four-card** is also called **bomb-card**, it can be used to beat all other card type and **four-card** with a lower rank (6666 can beat 33, 5555, 3331, 8888KJ)

**Definition9**: **rocket-card** is a combination of r and R, it can beat all other card type.

***Give out Rule5:*** The same as **Give out Rule4** and tow additional card types (from Def8 ~ Def9) are allowed to discard.

***Give out Rule6:*** Player C is added as a teammate of B, he will discard card following B, either B or C discards all hand cards first will be winner of B and C.

I believe there exists an linear algorithm for Give out Rule1 ~ Rule3, someone can provide such a method and related informations, or prove that the problem is exponential.

Comment: The winner can only be determined ahead of time if both players play completely deterministic.

Comment: The rules are incomplete. What happens when neither player can discard a card?

Comment: I have edited the text and the rule is complete now :-)

Comment: So, you have depicted the search trees that are needed. Now it is a matter of letting a program do this via an minimax/alphabeta algorithm. Is the question: how to implement an algorithm to go through the search tree and determine who is the winner? Is Minimax/Alpha-beta not the answer to that?

Comment: Minimax/Alpha-beta is a good start, but it is really difficult to find an evaluation function. Actually I am looking for a linear solution at least can solve the problem of Rule1 ~ Rule3:

Comment: http://h5hlddz.qq.com/hlddz-web/ddz.html  the most popular doudizhu game in china, you can have a try.

Comment: The more variations you add to the question, the less likely you will get an answer to this question. I would suggest you stick at one form of the game only. If minimax is not the answer you are looking for, I cannot help you. I don't think there can be a solution found in linear time.

Comment: Without looking at *your simplified version*: (1) if minmax is not an option because of missing evaluation functions / or because the search-depth is too high to traverse completely, [MCTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search) would be a very appropriate approach (no evaluation-function needed; but could be added). (2) it's very likely, that this game is np-hard at least which rules out a simple linear algorithm to determine the winner. (your link above is just a black-window for me; chrome-browser)

Comment: (1) I believe it is impossible to find a linear algorithm to solve all Give-out-Rule case, but I do believe there exists a solution to the simple case (Rule1 ~ Rule3). (2) the black-window  issue may induces that you are in private mode?

Comment: Black-window was due to flash-blocking. Could have mentioned that it's a flash-site. I expected a test-based game description. What is your task about? You want to implement an AI? If yes, i would definitly not start with implementing linear-time inference-engines for parts of the rules. When the complete game is np-hard or worse, they do not help much and it would be much easier to just implement a simple MCTS approach.

Comment: The site is actually Html5 rather than flash. I am  working on an AI project indeed, your advice has already put on my agenda. But I want to find an non-exponent algorithm for Rule1 ~ Rule3 first.

Comment: You should include all the relevant information in the question, in this case what Rule1~Rule3 is about.

Comment: This problem is most likely exponential. But since each player has a very limited number of cards on hand (you used 5 cards in an example) you can generate the whole _decision tree_, it's not a problem.